# How to get SFTP on Ubuntu working again? Should I try to fix it or reinstall?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows, sftp

*Update: Added output from two more logs, and am now only tailing the last twenty lines...so you can* ***see*** *the relevant lines.*

---

After six months of working perfectly, SFTP on my Ubuntu machine [has suddenly stopped working](https://superuser.com/q/864776/313690). I never configured or installed it, it just worked.

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

The only way I use SFTP is to map my server as a lettered drive on my Windows machine, with [SFTP Net Drive Free](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/). As described in painful detail in the post linked above, I've also confirmed that it doesn't work in [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/) (an SFTP Net Drive competitor) and [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/). I've only used SFTP Net Drive, though.

Importantly, I created a new temporary account, and I ***can*** SFTP with it, which implies that this is an Ubuntu configuration issue with my current account.

The only customization I've done is to add aliases and alias-like functions to the `.bashrc` file, and a couple new commands into `.inputrc` (like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571852/alternatives-for-variable-string-substitution-in-bash), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter/27914640#27914640), [here](https://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/aliasfunction/), and [here](https://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/bashgrepdeletehistory/). If any SFTP-related settings were changed, it was a freak accident.

I've reinstalled SFTP Net Drive, restarted both computers, and still nothing works.

Following the tips in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1399131):

> *Check that (usually at the end, although the order of the configs don't matter) the sftp subsystem is defined in the openssh-server config and not commented out.*

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

This is there exactly.

> *And also check that the file of the subsystem exists*

```
file /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server: ELF 32-bit
```

My output:

```
file /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=469f88be752153898a1e5a4787e6145e6eb99bd3, stripped
history -a
```

> *check if the file has the read and executable flags set*

```
ls -l /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63484 2009-10-22 22:36 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

The permissions are exactly the same.

> *check the logs for error messages*

```
tail -20 /var/log/auth.log
tail -20 /var/log/messages.log
```

I attempted to login with SFTP Net Drive at 9:39 pm, and then output the logs.

`auth.log`:

```
sudo tail -20 /var/log/auth.log
Jan 14 21:37:18 myservername sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 14 21:38:27 myservername sshd[3068]: Invalid user admin from 123.45.67.891
Jan 14 21:38:27 myservername sshd[3068]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Jan 14 21:38:27 myservername sshd[3068]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 14 21:38:27 myservername sshd[3068]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=li707-40.members.linode.com
Jan 14 21:38:28 myservername sshd[3068]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 123.45.67.891 port 45702 ssh2
Jan 14 21:38:29 myservername sshd[3068]: Received disconnect from 123.45.67.891: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 14 21:38:40 myservername sshd[3071]: Accepted password for myusername from 173.61.202.27 port 54007 ssh2
Jan 14 21:38:40 myservername sshd[3071]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myusername by (uid=0)
Jan 14 21:38:43 myservername sshd[3071]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user myusername
Jan 14 21:38:49 myservername sudo:    myusername : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/myusername ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -50 /var/log/syslog
Jan 14 21:38:49 myservername sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by myusername(uid=0)
Jan 14 21:38:49 myservername sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 14 21:40:01 myservername CRON[3151]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user smmsp by (uid=0)
Jan 14 21:40:01 myservername CRON[3151]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user smmsp
Jan 14 21:41:00 myservername sudo:    myusername : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/myusername ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -20 /var/log/auth.log
Jan 14 21:41:00 myservername sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by myusername(uid=0)
Jan 14 21:41:00 myservername sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 14 21:41:17 myservername sudo:    myusername : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/myusername ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -50 /var/log/auth.log
Jan 14 21:41:17 myservername sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by myusername(uid=0)
history -a
```

`sudo tail -20 /var/log/syslog`:

```
sudo tail -20 /var/log/syslog
Jan 14 17:56:39 myservername /usr/sbin/irqbalance: Balancing is ineffective on systems with a single cache domain.  Shutting down
Jan 14 17:56:43 myservername sm-mta[981]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Jan 14 17:56:46 myservername ntpdate[465]: step time server 91.189.89.199 offset 1.521544 sec
Jan 14 17:57:02 myservername ntpdate[1074]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.000019 sec
Jan 14 17:57:59 myservername kernel: [   83.690027] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Jan 14 18:00:01 myservername CRON[1183]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 18:17:01 myservername CRON[1438]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 14 18:20:01 myservername CRON[1536]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 18:40:01 myservername CRON[1971]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 19:00:01 myservername CRON[2086]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 19:17:01 myservername CRON[2187]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 14 19:20:01 myservername CRON[2204]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 19:40:01 myservername CRON[2317]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 20:00:01 myservername CRON[2432]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 20:17:01 myservername CRON[2531]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 14 20:20:01 myservername CRON[2548]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 20:40:01 myservername CRON[2663]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 21:00:01 myservername CRON[2843]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Jan 14 21:17:01 myservername CRON[2942]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 14 21:20:01 myservername CRON[2959]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
history -a
```

`$ sudo tail -20 /var/log/messages.log`

```
sudo tail -20 /var/log/messages.log
tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/messages.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
history -a
```

I don't know what this means. Accepted password for my account, but not for root. I copy my password from 1Password, paste it into the console and it works. Then paste it into SFTP Net Drive and it doesn't.

I also noticed a "Could not load host key" error earlier in the log, and [this page](http://trick77.com/2014/09/30/could-not-load-host-key-etcsshssh_host_ed25519_key/) says to execute `ssh-keygen -A`, which I did. I don't understand if it made a difference.

---

Is this something I should try to fix? Or should I just "reinstall" SFTP again? (Although I never installed it to begin with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that SFTP crashes if any text is output to the console. I added an echo to my `~/.bashrc`, which killed it.

I've added the following to the very top of `.bashrc`:

```
:<<COMMENT
  SFTP breaks if any thing is output to the shell, and it doesn't need
  anything in .bashrc anyway.

  Description of the following line of code: "If file descriptor 0, or 
  'the input' is connected to a terminal, which is true when you do: 
     ssh yourhost 
  but not when you do:
     ssh yourhost bash -s < script # here it's connected to 'script', a file"

  See
  - https://serverfault.com/questions/485487/use-bashrc-without-breaking-sftp
  - http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#2.9
COMMENT
[ -t 0 ] || return
```

In addition, I've moved the echo, which I intended as a login intro message, to `/etc/motd`, as described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/407109/265174)

---

Thanks to dualbus and ishikawa on #bash.